# AWS CloudFormation Property validation failure: [Encountered unsupported properties in {/ContainerProperties/Environment

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation

I'm creating a POC with AWS Batch. To create the infra I'm ussing AWS CloudFormation.

I have a problem with the resource **AWS::Batch::JobDefinition**

```yaml
  ContentInputJob:
    Type: "AWS::Batch::JobDefinition"
    Properties:
      Type: Container
      ContainerProperties: 
        Environment:
          - name: SECRETS
            value: '**********'
        Command: 
          - -v
          - process
          - new-file
          - -o
        Image: !Join ['', [!Ref 'AWS::AccountId','.dkr.ecr.', !Ref 'AWS::Region', '.amazonaws.com/', !Ref ImageName ] ]
        JobRoleArn: !Ref BatchContainerIAMRole
        Memory: 128 
        Vcpus: 2
      JobDefinitionName: DemoContentInput
      RetryStrategy: 
        Attempts: 1
```

Creating the stack fails with... "Property validation failure: [Encountered unsupported properties in {/ContainerProperties/Environment/0}: [name, value]]"

I read:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-batch-jobdefinition-containerproperties.html#cfn-batch-jobdefinition-containerproperties-environment
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-batch-jobdefinition-environment.html

I tried this too:

```yaml
  ContentInputJob:
    Type: "AWS::Batch::JobDefinition"
    Properties:
      Type: Container
      ContainerProperties: 
        Environment:
          - SECRETS: '**********'
        Command: 
          - -v
          - process
          - new-file
          - -o
        Image: !Join ['', [!Ref 'AWS::AccountId','.dkr.ecr.', !Ref 'AWS::Region', '.amazonaws.com/', !Ref ImageName ] ]
        JobRoleArn: !Ref BatchContainerIAMRole
        Memory: 128 
        Vcpus: 2
      JobDefinitionName: DemoContentInput
      RetryStrategy: 
        Attempts: 1
```

Then I get "Property validation failure: [Encountered unsupported properties in {/ContainerProperties/Environment/0}: [SECRETS]]"

How is the syntax for this? I need more than one environment variable.

```yaml
      ContainerProperties: 
        Environment:
          - name: SECRETS
            value: '**********'
          - name: SECRETS2
            value: '**********'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions is use Capital letters.

```yaml
      ContainerProperties: 
        Environment:
          - Name: SECRETS
            Value: '**********'
          - Name: SECRETS2
            Value: '**********'
```

Answer (score 1):

Recommend trying the [CloudFormation Linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/) in [VSCode](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cfn-lint-visual-studio-code) to see some of these errors inline while authoring templates along with autocompletion and documentation links:

[image: Visual Studio Code extension]

```
[cfn-lint] E3002: Invalid Property Resources/ContentInputJob/Properties/ContainerProperties/Environment/0/name
[cfn-lint] E3002: Invalid Property Resources/ContentInputJob/Properties/ContainerProperties/Environment/0/value
```

Comment: Thanks Pat, But I  this mesages are like mine. The solutions is use Capital Letters. Name and Value

Comment: Property autocompletion will prevent it from happening again though :)